# How to run a jenkins pipeline job in a single dynamic docker agent?

Tags: jenkins

I have setup a dynamic docker agent to run the Jenkins build.
But the agents are destroyed immediately after the build has been completed which is expected. I want to run a downstream job on the same docker agent.

Is it possible?

Comment: Share your pipeline.

Comment: I'm using build triggers to run the downstream job on same node.
https://i.imgur.com/pqk4LFt.png